# Find direction(clockwise anti-clockwise) MKPolyline drawn on MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I am using **MKPolylineRenderer** to render series of polylines. I am facing challenge with deciding clockwise/anticlockwise direction of its drawing on map. I tried my best put my issue. I am attaching screenshot for more clarity.[image]

**Approach:** I am still exploring. To find direction between two Polylines [clockwise and anti-clockwise]

Let me know your thought :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem using formula referred at [forum](https://python-forum.io/thread-14188-post-63842.html#pid63842)

**Solution** : Actually We need two lines(polylines) to decide direction. I am   considering first two polyline in my case to decide its direction.
I am sharing my swift version code here.

```
func polylinesAngle(line1: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], line2: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
    let VA1 = MKMapPoint(line1[0])
    
    // Common Vertx
    let VA2 = MKMapPoint(line1[1])
    let VB1 = MKMapPoint(line2[0])
    
    let VB2 = MKMapPoint(line2[1])
    
    let dAx = VA2.x - VA1.x
    let dAy = VA2.y - VA1.y
    let dBx = VB2.x - VB1.x
    let dBy = VB2.y - VB1.y
    
    let angle = atan2(dAx * dBy - dAy * dBx, dAx * dBx + dAy * dBy).(180.0 / .pi) // to degree
}
```

**// Clockwise :** Positive value

**// Anticlockwise :** Negative Value